# Why am I getting no satellite signal after running electrical cable alongside the satellite cable?

Tags: electrical, wiring

I am adding exterior lights and I ran exterior grade electrical wire along the side of the house and tied this wire to the Dish Satellite wire running in the same direction.  Now I have no Dish signal.

Did I cause this by tying these cables together?

Comment: ***NEC 2014 800.133(A)(2) Other Applications.** Communications wires and cables shall be separated at least 50 mm (2 in.) from conductors of any electric light, power, Class 1, non–power-limited fire alarm, or medium-power network-powered broadband communications circuits.*

Answer (score 4):

In order to rule out that you didn't somehow damage the coax, cut power to the circuit and see if this restores the signal. If it does, then yes you've introduced enough interference to prevent reception.  If it doesn't, then you might have damaged the coax.

RG6 Quad Shield might help but generally it should be 8-12" away.

As an aside, tying electric cable to a Telco cable doesn't sound like a safe installation. You might want to contact a licensed electrician.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this may well be caused by interference. Power cables are not supposed to be run near low-voltage telecom/data cables, and I wouldn't be surprised if satellite cables were subject to the same interference. I don't known if there's a specific rule about how far apart they need to be, but I've heard 8". If the runs are long and straight you might err on the side of more distance.

Of course, you may also have disturbed the Dish connections by fiddling with them.

Comment: Minimum I have heard has been 6", but on my jobs the techs always preferred 12" minimum, 24" when possible, crossing over when needed, at a 90 degree angle.